# php export to csv is shifting column when no data is present

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I am getting all the values from the database as an array. As its a huge database I am just showing two rows for reference.

So the array goes like this by doing `print_r($data);`

```
array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [listing_id] => 5975
            [category_id] => A la Carte|Bar|Banquet|Champagne Bar|Cajun Creole|German
            [listing_name] => test-chris
            [image_name] => SBCTR Logo.jpg
            [address] => 1 surfe parade
            [phone] => 0402331482
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [listing_id] => 5974
            [category_id] => 
            [listing_name] => Charlie Lovett
            [image_name] => SBCTR Logo.jpg
            [address] =>  
            [phone] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [listing_id] => 5973
            [category_id] => Banquet|Champagne Bar
            [listing_name] => Charlie Lovett
            [image_name] => SBCTR_1234 Logo.jpg
            [address] =>  
            [phone] => 1231234567
        )        
)
```

Now I want to export is as csv. So I made my php code like this

```
function export_to_csv($data, $filename="data.csv", $delim = ',', $newline = "\n", $enclosure = '' ) {
   $string_to_export = '';
   $c = 0;
   foreach( $data as $row) {
    $string_to_export .= $enclosure.implode($enclosure.$delim.$enclosure, ( $c ? array_values($row) : array_keys($row)) ).$enclosure.$newline; 
    $c++;
    }
        header('Content-type: text/csv;charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        //echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
    echo $string_to_export;
    exit();
 }
 export_to_csv($data, "data.csv");
```

Now when I opened the csv I saw that if in a row there is no data for a column then the next column just doing shift to one step back. Like this

```
listing_id    category_id               listing_name        image_name          address          phone

 5975         A la Carte|Bar....        test-chris          SBCTR Logo.jpg      1 surfe parade   1482

 5974         Charlie Lovett            SBCTR Logo.jpg

 5973         Banquet|Champagne Bar    Charlie Lovett       SBCTR_1234 Logo.jpg  1231234567
```

As you can see the data is shifting to the previus column in 2nd and 3rd row. So can someone tell me how to solve this. Sorry but I can't change the database. Any help and suggestions wil be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: why don't you continue here only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590546/php-make-csv-file-for-the-array/30591037#30591037

Comment: Do you know that this can be done directly with your database? An example with mySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sorry but I can't make any changes to the database

Comment: ???? This way doesn't need to change anything in the database.

Comment: Try setting your enclosure to '"'